# Sass - Media queries not applying (Jekyll)

Tags: css, sass

I made my website through Jekyll using Sass, I was making the website responsive but for some reasons, the media queries don't apply to the div class.

style.sass

```
 .img-link
    width: calc(32% - 14px)
    border: 2px solid white

@media (max-width: 700px)
  .img-link
      width: calc(97% - 14px)
```

I am using Sass on a mixin (Jade file)

```
mixin img(link, img, color)
  a(href="#{link}").img-link
```

Compiled CSS form:

```
  section.notes .img-link {
    width: -webkit-calc(32% - 14px);
    width: calc(32% - 14px);
    border: 2px solid white;
    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      section.notes .img-link .img-link {
        width: -webkit-calc(97% - 14px);
        width: calc(97% - 14px); } }
    section.notes .img-link img {
      width: 100%; }

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .img-link {
    width: -webkit-calc(97% - 14px);
    width: calc(97% - 14px); } }
```

Compiled HTML

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<section class="notes">

<div class="flex flex--center">

<div data-orig-color="#ea4c89" class="col-3 flex flex--center dribbble">

<div class="col-3">

<p class="home-lead">...Updating...</p>
<a href="#" data-color="orange" class="img-link"><img src="assets/img/design-img/drib-1.jpg"/></a>
<a href="#" data-color="#aeb3b0" class="img-link"><img src="assets/img/design-img/drib-2.jpg"/></a>
```

Comment: What does the compiled CSS/HTML look like?

Comment: @cimmanon I added the compiled CSS to the post. Take a look.

Comment: [Specificity in CSS](http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) - further reading for OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the generated CSS, `section.notes .img-link` is more specific, and would take precedence over `.img-link` in the media query.

You need to make your selector inside the media query as least as specific as the one outside it.

---

Looking at is a second time, your generated CSS comes up with these selectors:

```
section.notes .img-link
    width: calc(32% - 14px);

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) section.notes .img-link .img-link
    width: calc(97% - 14px);

section.notes .img-link img
    width: 100%;

@media (max-width: 700px) .img-link
    width: calc(97% - 14px);
```

so without the HTML structure, I'm not even sure which one of these holds the styles you are talking about. It certainly looks like a specificity problem though...

Comment: I added the compiled HTML, but how do I make it specific?